# AndroidAnnotations integration with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-annotations

I try to use AndroidAnnotation in my Android project.
In fact, I've a library project that contains all the business logic, it's in this project that I want use AndroidAnnotations, its build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':android-sliding-layer-lib')
    compile 'net.simonvt.menudrawer:menudrawer:3.0.6@aar'
    compile project(':pull-to-refresh')
    compile project(':view-pager-indicator')
    compile project(':month-year-date-picker')
    compile project(':pull-to-refresh-gallery')
    compile project(':facebook-sdk')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.1"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.1"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20'

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

The generation works, for example, my class "ReadMoreFindContactsFragment_" is correctly generatad, I can see it on Android studio.

I also have a build.gradle file in the root path :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I can launch the app on my phone and AndroidAnnotations fragment works but when I use "Rebuild project" on AndroidStudio I've this message :

"Error:/home/rpotier/devhome/workspace/mobile-android/shared-project/src/com/shared/ui/phone/ReadMoreFindContactsActivity.java:6: The import com.shared.ui.fragment.ReadMoreFindContactsFragment_ cannot be resolved"

Could you help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is `ReadMoreFindContactsFragment` correctly annotated with `@EFragment`?

Comment: Yes he's annotated with @EFragment

Comment: You said the "rebuild project" command does not generate the enhanced class. You also said you said another time it worked. What command did you use in that case?
Your OP is a little bit confusing.